# Is it necessary to buy Disneyland Paris tickets in advance?

Tags: tickets, paris, disney

I want to visit the Paris Disneyland soon, however I'm not sure about the date. Checking out their [booking website](https://www.booktickets.disneylandparis.com/tnsa64/live/shop/9/MAINUSCD/pluto/index.php?&selected_tab_key=49&CNSACTION=DO_CHANGE_TAB&affid=SECUTIX&tduid=32454335543R) I can see that none of the tickets are for a specific date and that I can buy a ticket for tomorrow for the same price as for next month.

So the questions are:

1. Is it necessary to buy tickets in advance?
2. Is it possible to buy one on-the-spot at the venue itself for the same price?

Comment: (1) Don't go on weekends. (2) Unfortunately the on-site hotels are absurdly overpriced, but a fantastic thing with incredible benefits; an overwhelming advantage is you don't have to queue to either buy the ticket or get in the gate, or car line. I love Disneyland FR and hope you do, too!  Remember to bring your ultimate chill attitude. Your children literally LIKE waiting in the line with you for two hours for each ride, just go with it! The fancy-ass character restaurant (named "Chez Belle" or similar at each Disneyland) is expensive but utterly awesome for kids; incredibly good performers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific advanced purchase discounts are not common at any Disney park, but they might be available in certain circumstances.  Even then, it's not really an advance purchase discount, it's just a promotion (yes, there is a difference).

1. No.  It is not necessary in any way.
2. Yes.

But, while there likely isn't an advanced purchase discount, there are a number of discounts available depending on where you live and military service.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can buy in advance. And if I were you, I would book in advance. The waiting queue can be sometime annoying there. And as you'll encounter waiting queues at the rides in most of the cases, if you can avoid one at the ticket counter, this is already good time saved :)

You can also buy tickets directly tickets but the price won't be discounted. You can find discounted prices online. I have never found discounted prices directly at the park entrance, only reduced prices if you were buying pass for the 2 parks at the same time.

Adding for you an offer that you might find interesting :
http://www.voyage-prive.com/fiche-produit/details/58791/b1